# Android Over Image Selection Ocr Text

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, text-recognition

I have a question, firstly I am trying to do text recognition like ios/google lens.

Exm ios -> https://youtu.be/KOViYNOf6Nw?t=38

Exm android -> https://youtu.be/7PyC-OIz34o?t=30

I'm working on a custom view for this, but it's taking longer than I expected, I add a coordinate-based cursor and feed it various motion events. I also got support from the open source code below.

Github -> https://github.com/TechNikh/Android-Open-Lens-OCR-Text-Scanner/tree/develop/app/src/main/java/com/technikh/imagetextgrabber/widgets

Is there a simpler way or can I trigger selection in text view?

Also, cursorum works hovering in long texts. Is there any chance to trigger the default copy/share ... menu, I also developed it myself. Using the Ballon library

I use firebase text recognition

I'm open to your suggestions :)